# Cypress - cy.visit() failed trying to load

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

**Problem**

I am running an integration test for Cypress which works fine locally but fails when I run it in Gitlab. The error I am receiving is while using the `cy.visit()` command that results in the following error:

```
CypressError: `cy.visit()` failed trying to load:
http://localhost:3000/ The response we received from your web server
was:
  404: Not Found
```

**Configuration**

I launch the test with the following commands:

```
tests:
  image: cypress/base:10
  stage: tests
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run test:ci
```

The commands look like this in my `package.json`:

```
      "scripts": {
        "start:ci": "serve dist --no-clipboard --listen ${PORT:-3000}",
        "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test && npm run test:jest && npm 
run test:cypress",
        "test:ci": "start-server-and-test start:ci http://localhost:3000 test",
        "test:cypress": "cypress run --headless",
        "test:jest": "jest",
      },
```

**Research**

I have looked into the error and found [this](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3245) thread which helped me understand the issue a little bit. I then tried adding the following config to my `cypress.json` file:

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3000"
}
```

but I still get the same error. Why would this be?

Comment: Try to add `wait-on` and see if it still fails https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction#Solutions

Comment: That did not help i'm afraid

Comment: did it give the same error or something else? I want to know if issue is start:ci failed to start on gitlab or cypress test config issue

Comment: It just times out and then the process runs out of memory. I tried another approach from the page you sent using the `start-server-and-test` which is recommended by them which you can see as the `test:ci` script but it was the same result

Comment: if it times out it means that nothing is running on localhost:3000, is this how you start server locally `serve dist --no-clipboard --listen ${PORT:-3000}` ??

Comment: yes, and it works fine locally - no errors or anything

Comment: ok, then probably you didnt install packages on the CI, unlike your local machine. You need to run `npm install` or something similar first because you are starting the server on a cypress image which has nothing installed on it other than cypress

Comment: You can see it does the install with `- npm ci` command. It also uses the image: cypress/base:10 which has all the system dependencies

Comment: oh, I missed it, you are right. It should install everytihng

Comment: Does it work locally if you make an entirely fresh clone in a new folder and just run the same commands? It's possible there's some basic step you are forgetting and that will help rule that out.

Comment: It works fine locally

Comment: So just to be sure, do you still use you launch commands as displayed in your post with `npm ci - npm run start:ci - npm run test` or did you change it to `npm ci - npm run test:ci`?

Comment: I actually tried variations of both but the one in this issue is npm ci - npm run test:ci. WIll update the code to reflect that

Comment: Is it relying on anything else locally? Backend?

Comment: Have you tried to use a different port when you run your app? Instead of 3000?

Comment: For me this happens only when I run more than one test... one test passes every time

Comment: which CI tool are you using? I was using GitHub actions & I just had to add `start: yarn start` in the `with` section of the yaml. here's the file in case you're interested - https://github.com/sohammondal/react-data-table/blob/f346fdb6e507453f23d6b712aaeab0a71166dfc5/.github/workflows/cypress.yml

Answer (score 1):

Add a slash to the end of the url or  if you can remove the slash when placing the request.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone had the same issue we were facing which is that the `cypress.json` file was not in the root. We had it in the cypress folder.
Once moved to the root folder, cypress was able to find the file and therefore also the `baseUrl`.

Comment: `cypress.json` is deprecated, but if adding a `baseUrl` works, then you can add it via `cypress.config.ts` instead.

Comment: you can also instead of having to move your `cypress.config.ts`, add it in your `tsconfig.ts` file in the `include` section -> `"include":["path/to/your/cypress.config.ts"]`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a slow running test that triggered a timeout of cypress itself.

I could fix it by increasing the value of:

```json
{
  "responseTimeout": 120e3
}
```

There's a [documentation of all possible timeout](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Timeouts). Yours may differ.

You may also want to [only increase it for certain tests](https://filiphric.com/waiting-in-cypress-and-how-to-avoid-it) and not globally for all tests so that failed tests won't take that much more longer.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may experience a similar issue, running `yarn build` before running the tests solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problems, even though all of my tests were running before without any issues.

My initial error-message was:

```
cy.visit() failed trying to load:
http://localhost:4200/settings
```

My webserver was available, I have not had any weird configurations and I was simply trying to visit a page in my cypress tests.

When I looked into the details of the error, I saw the following:

```
From Node.js Internals:
  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4200
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16)
```

I could fix the issue with simply running:

```
npm i axios
npm i
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be two different problems:

1. Do you have sure your page is running healthy in http://localhost:3000? Maybe you can try to run a step first to make a request to this address and see if the status response is 200 and the content of this request
2. I will also suggest to you to run your test in GitLab in a different way also using wait-on, so first install wait-on dependence with `npm i -D wait-on` after that create a new script in your package.json and use this new script to run in Gitlab like:

   `test:gitlab: "wait-on http://localhost:3000 && cypress run --config pageLoadTimeout=60000,retries=3,defaultCommandTimeout=4000 --browser chrome"`